# Statsd & Graphite - get data as CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, graphite, statsd

I use statsd for measuring stats and Graphite for displaying these. Anyway, I would like to do a more sophisticated analysis in statistical software, to find out the relations between various variables.

In order to do this, I need the "raw" data, which are usually displayed in Graphite as color lines. Is it possible to get the data in CSV format? Data sampled to 1 entry per 10 seconds will be perfect, and that's statsd default behavior, I think.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. And it is straightforward.

```
Server: graphite.example.com
Metric: Graphite.system.data.ip-10-0-0-1.load
```

As you might be aware, Graphite has a URL API.

```
graphite.example.com/render/?target=Graphite.system.data.ip-10-0-0-1.load
```

Returns the line-graph. To get data in `csv` or even `json`, append- `&format=json`

```
graphite.example.com/render/?target=Graphite.system.data.ip-10-0-0-1.load&format=csv
```

Comment: Yes, it works great. And I have also discovered the graphic API itself. Thank you.